# how to download zip file having jpeg image from database in c#

Tags: c#, zip

I have to download all photo in zip file using c#, but whenever I am downloading zip file, I get all photo downloaded but getting  its crc32 code  00000

When I repair the zip file then I can see downloaded photo.
I have used Ionic dll.

my code is :

```
public void downloadallimage()
    { 
        DataTable dtpic;

             dtpic = DBData.getDataTable(DBData.DataPath, "select * from Table");

       ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtpic.Rows)
        {

            zip.AddEntry(dr["UploadedFileName"].ToString(), (byte[])dr["Photo1"]);

        }

        var zipMs = new MemoryStream();
        zip.Save(zipMs);
        byte[] fileData = zipMs.GetBuffer();
        zipMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zipMs.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=docs.zip ");
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Can you shed some light on the downloading process? How do you download with what and where?

Comment: its an method which is being call on button click event in asp.net using MS sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetBuffer returns the internal memory stream buffer. It could contains unused bytes. If you want the real memory stream bytes use ToArray() method instead. Or you could use the WriteTo method to write directly to the Response Outputstream.

Comment: Thanks its Works...:)

Answer (score 0):

now my code works fine for downloading image in zip file.

public void downloadallimage()

```
{ 
    DataTable dtpic;
         dtpic = DBData.getDataTable(DBData.DataPath, "select * from Table");
   ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtpic.Rows)
    {
        zip.AddEntry(dr["UploadedFileName"].ToString(), (byte[])dr["Photo1"]);
    }
    var zipMs = new MemoryStream();
    zip.Save(zipMs);
    byte[] fileData = zipMs.ToArray();
    zipMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    zipMs.Flush();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=docs.zip ");
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
    Response.End();
}
```